# Blob, внутренняя процедура, импорт-экспорт файла

Tags: firebird, interbase, процедуры

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли с помощью внутренней процедуры (Firebird) экспортировать данные в файл из blob поля (в данном случае **.xls*) и наоборот импортировать файл в blob?

Заранее спасибо,

Comment: "экспортировать данные в файл из blob поля" - имеется ввиду просто содержимое blob сохранить на диск или как-то обработать xls-файл, содержащийся в blob?

Comment: Поясню: на клиент приходят файлы, их нужно сохранять на сервере, а на сервере нельзя расшаривать папки.
Вот я и думал файлы через blob поле перекидывать с клиента на сервер (в blob на клиенте загружу, а на сервере, чтоб его кто-то выгрузил в директорию). Да потом наоборот нужно будет делать, если клиент потребует эти файлы назад, их нужно будет загрузить на сервере в blob поле

Comment: Проще завести вторую базу и сразу хранить там файлы как blob. Также можно написать мини-приложение, которое будет крутиться на сервере и загружать/выгружать как обычный клиент. Третий вариант - написать набор UDF, которые будут работать с файловой системой.

Comment: Да, я как раз пробую тут одну из *udf*  http://www.ibase.ru/d_udf/ (**BlobSaveLoad**)

Comment: В принципе, если миновать таблицу, а чтение и запись делать хранимыми процедурами, то эти UDF вас полностью устроят. Только нужно сделать проверку, что путь в пределах разрешенной папки на сервере